# convert string to json and than read the json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yql

First of all, I'm fairly new to json, so please forgive me if I've made a terrible mistake. I've got some code that gets a json object from a website using YQL It returns it as a string. So now I want to parse this into a json object and than read it.
This is my code:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url=%22http://iphone-api.uitzendinggemist.nl/v1/episodes.json%22%20and%20xpath=%27*%27&format=json", function(data) {
console.log(data);
content = data.query.results.html.body.p;
json = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + content + ")"));
str = json.revoked;
$('#table').append('<li>' + str + '</li>');
});
```

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7UKwM/)

I just can't figure out why this gives me undifined, instead of the value it should give.

So now my question was if someone here knows why it isn't working properly.

Answer (score 0):

The `json` variable is an array, you need to access an index.

`string = json[0].revoked;`

Answer (score 0):

You have many many many errors in your code. You should try to understand each step that you are doing, it looks like you don't. [Here's a fork of your code that does something](http://jsfiddle.net/hdSbU/15/), I'm not sure what you want it to do. I'll tell you few things you did wrong:

1. Use `var` keyword when declaring new variables within functions
2. Don't parse JSON using `eval()`, but use some parser. E.g. [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/). Using `eval()` is a security risk, as returned script WILL be executed on client and you should only be interested in getting data.
3. When constructing HTML, take care to encode text that you want displayed. In your case, don't concatenate strings (`'<li>' + str + '</li>'`). You can use jQuery (`$('<li>').text(str)`).
4. Don't add `li` elements to a `table` element. Either add them to `ul` or `ol` elements, or in case of tables create rows and cells.
5. It is completely unclear why you would eval, and them stringify an object. You end up with same exact data.